# Can I cluster document from a local file?

Tags: carrot2

I have already used carrot2 for my clustering project. I integrate carrot2 with my php codes so I use DCS. 
My question is "can I cluster documents from a local file?" since there's an option 'From XML File' in parameter 'Document Source' in the welcome screen of carrot2 (Quick start - Document Clustering Server - Carrot2).
If it can be, how could it be?I mean, how are the example codes to cluster from a local file? (considered the file is xml type and uses xml format specified by carrot2).
In the 'example.php' there's an example code for clustering from external data source (etools) but I confuse how to change this code to cluster from xml file.
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

When you choose 'From XML File' in Carrot2 DCS, it is the browser that uploads the local file to the DCS for clustering. To get the same functionality in your PHP code, your PHP code would have to [accept file uploads](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and then [send the content to the DCS for clustering](https://github.com/carrot2/carrot2/blob/master/applications/carrot2-dcs/examples/php5/example.php#L101).